# Prestashop: Insert a module manually in the html

Tags: html, prestashop

I'm trying to insert a prestashop module manually directly into the html code. For example in the header.tpl I want to insert the categories module, but if I copy and paste the exact code from the blockcategories.tpl file, I receive the following message:

undefinded index: blockCategTree in ...

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: you always need a hook for the module to hook on to, modules have are not just .tpl...

Comment: Ok, thank you. The fact is that I'm new to use prestashop. So, which is the best way to use the module like a html block so that I can place and style them as I want?

Comment: Use the generator here: https://validator.prestashop.com/generator  
You can generate a module easily, add your hooks and inject any content you want in those hooks.

Answer (score 2):

To place a module into your template you always need a hook;

[Hooks are a way to associate your code to some specific event (like a module),](http://events.http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks)
 
you can use the default hooks prestashop comes with or add your [custom hooks.](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/218291-create-custom-and-new-hook-in-ps-15/)

Comment: So, If I understand you correctly, I have to create a custom hook and add in it the category module, am I right?

Comment: you can do that or also check if there's any default PS hooks that can suite your needs